# Socket Programming Java, Server and Client

Tags: java, sockets

I wanna know what happens when the Client tries to receive a message from the Server and the Server had sent nothing
Or
How the client can know if the Server sent a message So it can receive it
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It depends on your setup and how you created the sockets. Generally, if you use asynchronous receiving then the "receive" should return immediately and you should get a notification or have a callback being invoked when something is received. If you use non-blocking sockets or functionality then it should also return immediately but with an "error" saying that there's nothing to be currently received. There should be plenty of documentation and examples all over the greater Internet about this, both generally and more specifically for Java.

Comment: I am not that expert I am trying to make a small application that works in the local to allow chatting between multiple clients  and I tried searching the internet and found nothing in if I was wording right anyway Thank you for your response